# What teamwork feats work with the Inquisitor (Reaper of Secrets) archetype for a ranged Inquisitor?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, archetype, inquisitor

I'm creating a crossbow-focused Inquisitor with the [Reaper of Secrets](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/archetypes/inquisitor-archetypes-paizo/reaper-of-secrets-inquisitor-archetype) archetype. The Reaper of Secrets grants a class feature called **Mind-Game Tactics** (replacing Solo Tactics) which essentially allows you to treat foes as if they have [Teamwork feats](http://archivesofnethys.com/Feats.aspx?Category=Teamwork) you possess.

However, with many Teamwork feats the result of doing so is nonsensical or offers no advantage whatsoever. For example, most Teamwork feats stipulate "when adjacent to an ally"...which when combined with Mind-Game Tactics can be translated to "when adjacent to a foe"...but an archer wants to avoid being adjacent to enemies as much as possible!

Which Teamwork feats work well with Mind-Game Tactics and a ranged Inquisitor? Thanks for your insights!

> **Mind-Game Tactics (Su):** At 3rd level, a reaper of secrets can read other creatures so well she can use their reactions to gain a tactical advantage. She treats any creature targeted by her soul-piercing gaze as if it were her ally and possessed the same teamwork feats as she does for the purposes of positioning and threatening when she determines whether she receives a benefit from her teamwork feats. She cannot use this ability to benefit from any teamwork feats that require particular actions from allies, such as Swap Places.
>
> For example, a reaper of secrets with the Precise Strike feat gains the bonus from that feat if she and the target of her soul-piercing gaze occupy flanking positions relative to the creature she attacks.
>
> This ability replaces solo tactics.

Comment: Mostly a heads up, you may be downvoted/voted to close because Stack Exchange isn't necessarily the best for making lists; I think this question is OK because it's very specific. Just be forewarned that you may have issues asking for 'everything that does ____' or 'works as ____'.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Ifusaso! Normally I DM 5e, so I'm not used to asking questions on Stack Exchange. If this isn't the right venue, I can always take it to Paizo's Pathfinder forums.

Comment: I'm going to experimentally reopen this. [We normally do not facilitate questions requesting a range of practical options](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7582/1204), but the novel constraints this question is facing may make it more workable. (Of course, the community may decide I have gone completely insane in reopening this and re-close it, as is their prerogative.)

Comment: Thanks doppelgreener! I'm hoping that Reaper of Secrets isn't intended for melee-focused inquisitors! Hard to understand the design intentions sometimes. For example: Target of Opportunity (which I don't yet qualify for) looked promising for ranged... except it specifies "against that opponent" which would mean if I used it with Mind-Game Tactics on an enemy, I'd ultimately end up targeting a friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any teamwork feats that serve for *"the purposes of positioning and threatening when she determines whether she receives a benefit from her teamwork feats"*.

In other words, you have to look for feats that require specific positioning or that your allies to be **threatening** the same target as you or similar effects. Once they become a (temporary) "ally", they simply have to be in the correct position or to be threatening the required target. To threaten, you must be armed and the target must be within your reach.

To list a few:

- [Cooperative Rend](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cooperative-rend-combat-teamwork) (for trolls), requires both of you to be threatening the same target.
- [Coordinated Reposition](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/coordinated-reposition-teamwork/), whenever your ally take a 5-foot step while threatening the same creature, you can also take a 5-foot step.
- [Seize the Moment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/seize-the-moment-combat-teamwork), whenever your ally confirms a critical hit against a target that you both threaten, you gain an attack of opportunity. There is little chance that your "ally" will attack their own ally, but it can happen (see the [confusion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/confusion) spell).
- [Coordinated Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/coordinated-shot-combat-teamwork), asks for that ally to be threatening your opponent to grant its bonus.
- [Tandem Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/tandem-trip-combat-teamwork) only requires your ally to be threatening the target, meaning that even a [ranged trip attempt](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/ranged-trip-combat-targeting/) should work.
- [Enfilading Fire](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/enfilading-fire-combat-teamwork) also should work, as it only requires two of your allies to be flanking the target.
- [Friendly Fire Maneuvers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/friendly-fire-maneuvers-combat-teamwork/) is related to positioning ([soft cover](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Cover)) should work both to ignore soft cover against your target and to gain +4 reflex bonus by spells cast by your "ally".

Feats that have a vague text and could not work:

- [Cooperative Distraction](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/coordinated-distraction-combat-teamwork), it doesnt necessarily specify what this enemy is, could be your enemy, or an enemy to both creatures. Depending on the case, the feat will not work because your enemy is not necessarily their enemy as well.

The major problem that I see with your idea is that most **ranged weapons do not threaten** enemies (see the [Snap Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/snap-shot-combat/) feat), and most of these teamwork feats will require you to threaten an enemy.

Comment: Thanks ShadowKras! Would you say Reaper of Secrets – by virtue of how teamwork feats are designed/worded – is intended to be a primarily melee-focused build? I'm starting to think so... and haven't been able to find a way  around it (e.g. with Combat Tricks).

Comment: The fact that there are so many more melee teamwork feats than ranged feats, shows that the problem is not with the *Reaper of Secrets*, but teamwork feats.

Comment: I was starting to get into convoluted work-arounds – like taking the Combat Stamina feat to get the Combat Trick of Lookout so I could "not be surprised when a potential enemy I'm focusing on attempts to surprise us" OR taking Ally Shield – but not sure how viable that is. I think you may be right, that while Reaper of Secrets is cool, it's just not supported for a ranged inquisitor currently.

Comment: I was able to hone it down to the following teamwork feats: Ally Shield, Bonded Mind, Escape Route, Friendly Fire, Lookout, and Overwhelm.

Comment: Bonded Mind has no threatened area or position condition, so it doesn't work. Lookout only works in the surprise round, if you managed to target them with your gaze, you are no longer surprised and already managed to act, or your group set up an ambush. Overwhelm is one of those who dont help much because you normally do not threaten with ranged weapons. The others are fine.

Comment: Thanks ShadowKras. Just tried running the Reaper of Secrets in the game I was invited into, and... I think Mind-Game Tactics just flat-out doesn't work narratively.

I get the mechanical idea...but as far as role-playing a convincing narrative of "I'm your ally, share my teamwork feat", it only really works if I role-play with a sentient NPC in advance of fighting them.

The DM vetoed my attempted use of it during a surprise round, and frankly I agreed with him. Narratively, it just doesn't make sense.